How to create an airflow sensor using k8s pod in (similar to KubernetesPodOperator)
I have recently started to use the KubernetesPodOperator that provides a lot of scale to airflow tasks (on 2.10) and has been working very well.
However, I would also like to kubernetes pods as sensor and there is no native sensor for this in airflow.
Following this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJB_f8YxemE, I attempted this:
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.pod import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.sensors.base import BaseSensorOperator

class KubernetesPodSensor(BaseSensorOperator, KubernetesPodOperator):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def poke(self, context):
    result = None
    try:
        result = KubernetesPodOperator.execute(self, context)
        return result["sensor_result"]
    except AirflowException:
        # not too sure why this is needed, following the video tutorial above
        if result is not None:
            self.logger.info(f'Sensor returned result: {result["sensor_result"]}.')
        raise

With the code above:

If sensor returns True on first execution, all works as planned

If it fails, it all works for the first execution, however, the sensor fails on second poke with the following warning:
[2024-09-30, 04:10:30 UTC] {baseoperator.py:405} WARNING - KubernetesPodSensor.execute cannot be called outside TaskInstance!
and exception:
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (404) Reason: Not Found


What am I doing wrong? Are there any alternatives for creating sensors that run a command inside a k8s pod?
